# How should I acquire a pointer to a function, for a function call in llvm, when using llvm-hs-pure?

Tags: haskell, llvm, llvm-ir

I have some function definitions using `function`, which is an initiator with some function defaults. The type of these definitions is the simplest possible, namely `ModuleBuilder Operand`.

I want to call these functions, using the call instruction, so I have to somehow acquire a pointer to these functions. I can `lift func`, where

```
func :: ModuleBuilder Operand
func = function "somename" params ty functionBody
```

The problem is that `function`, while it does return a pointer to the defined function, also emits the definition, which seems unnecessary to me.

The Module containing the definition of `func` is going to be linked to the target Module anyway, so the definition is already emitted. Is it correct to construct a pointer manually, using `GlobalReference ptrToFunc "somename"`? 
The pointer type is easily inferred since I know the LLVM type of the function beforehand.

If that is correct, then it answers my question, but I am not sure about it.

Comment: You cannot call a function in another module; you have to emit a definition in the module containing the call. See https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#module-structure for an example.

Comment: Ok, so `lift`ing is the way to go. Thanks a lot.